# How to define parameters in a PHP config file in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, import, parameters, config

I am using Symfony 4.0 and trying to use a PHP configuration file instead of a YAML file. So I went into the `services.yml` and imported the PHP file like so:

```
imports:
    - { resource: 'foobar.php' }
```

However I can not find any information online on how the parameters should be defined inside the PHP file. How can I define parameters in the `foobar.php` in order to be able to access them using `$container->getParameter()`? Do I need to set them using `$container->setParameter()` inside the imported PHP file?

Comment: It's seems like all parameters that not in 'php' format always converts to php array with help loaders (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/resources.html). So, it's possible that You have to create just common array with keys and values.
['parameters' => ['paramkey1' => 'paramvalue1', 'paramkey2' => 'paramvalue2']]

Comment: I did add an array inside but that doesn't do anything. I probably need to define it as a parameter or extend some class in order for it to work.

Comment: In the various config docs, notice that each example has a yaml xml php tab above them.  Click the php tag to see an example. https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's like in docs examples (https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html) :

```
<?php

// adds a new parameter
$container->setParameter('ahs_test', 'testvalue');
```

Variable `$container` will be available in script.